# Get current time of HTML5 video before seek

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html5-video, media-player

I have a `<video>` element in a HTML page and looking to record the sections of the video a user plays. I have a “play session” object that contains a start and end timestamp:

```js
class PlaySession {
  constructor(start) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = null;
  }

  finish(timestamp) {
    this.end = timestamp;
  }
}
```

When I “finish” the play session, I send the `start` and `end` values to an API endpoint for storing. I get the end timestamp by listening for the `pause` event raised by the video element.

The issue I have comes with seeking. If the video is currently playing and the user clicks elsewhere in the time scrubber, a `pause` event *is* raised, but the `currentTime` on the video is set to where the user clicked.

For example:

1. User starts watching video.
2. User watches 5 seconds of video.
3. User clicks to 30 seconds into video.
4. `pause` event is raised, `currentTime` is `30` instead of expected `5`.

There’s also the issue that if a user clicks a previous point in the video, then I’m going to get an `end` timestamp that’s *less than* the `start` timestamp.

When seeking, is there a way to get the `currentTime` *before* the seeking occurs?

Comment: annoyingly the `seeking` event seems to have the same issue. Only way I could make something work is tracking the timeUpdated event to keep an independent counter and use that value... shame the events don't fire in a helpful order (Chromium feature request?!)